# If $G$ is a connected graph and n is the length of the longest trail, show that if 2 trails are length $n$ then there is a vertex $v$ in both trails?

Tags: graph-theory

Attempt: I need to show that two disjoint trails in a connected graph have elements that are connected by a trail that has no middle elements from either trail. i.e for $a = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n)$ and $b = (b_1, b_2, ... b_n)$ as disjoint trails, there are elements $a_j$ and $b_k$ such that either $(a_j, b_k)$ is an arc of the graph, or a trail $(a_j, c_1, c_2, ..., b_k)$ such that no $c_i$ is in either of the original trails. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility is to consider two disjoint trails (as you mentioned). As the graph is connected, there exists a path that connects one vertex (call it $v_1$)of the first trail to a vertex (call it $v_2$) of the second trail. $v_1$ , in the first trail, can make sub-trails and one of them has a length $n_1\geq \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$. Same can be stated for $v_2$. Therefore there exist a sub-trail of length $n_2\geq \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ from $v_2$. As we have assumed that a path of length $n_3\geq 1$ connects $v_1$ to $v_2$, the length of the new trail is $n_1+n_2+n_3\geq 2\lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil+1 \geq n+1$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Since $G $ is connected, there is a trail $t $ from $a_1$ to $b_1$. Let $a_j$ be the last vertex of $a $ that this trail passes through. Can you see how to define $b_k $?

> Let $b_k $ be the first vertex of $b $ that $t $ visits after $a_j $. By choice of $a_j $ and $b_k $, there cannot be any vertices from $a $ or  $b $ between $a_j $ and $b_k $ on $t $, giving the desired trail (which may be a single edge).